# freebsd lsyncd fails

Tags: freebsd

It`s log file lsyncd working with /pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/css/ folder.

```
Wed Nov  6 13:27:11 2019 Normal: --- Startup, daemonizing ---
Wed Nov  6 13:27:11 2019 Normal: --- Startup ---
Wed Nov  6 13:27:11 2019 Normal: recursive startup rsync: /pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/css/ -> root@10.0.0.55:/pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/css/
sending incremental file list

sent 1,697 bytes  received 15 bytes  3,424.00 bytes/sec
total size is 974,876  speedup is 569.44
Wed Nov  6 13:27:11 2019 Normal: Startup of /pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/css/ -> root@10.0.0.55:/pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/css/ finished.
```

Its ok.

```
root@main2:/ # service lsyncd status
lsyncd is running as pid 2044.
```

It`s lsyncd working with /pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/newsimages/ folder.

```
Wed Nov  6 15:01:38 2019 Normal: --- Startup, daemonizing ---
Wed Nov  6 15:01:38 2019 Normal: --- Startup ---
```

It`s not ok. And nothing more. lsyncd is not running.

```
root@main2:/ # service lsyncd status
lsyncd is not running.
root@main2:/ # cat /usr/local/etc/lsyncd.conf
settings {
  logfile    = "/var/log/lsyncd.log",
  statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd.status",
  statusInterval = 1,
  maxProcesses = 1,
  insist = 1,
}
sync{
  default.rsync,
  delay = 0,
  source = "/pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/newsimages/",
  target = "root@10.0.0.55:/pool/www/yiiazertag/azertag/newsimages/",
  rsync = {
    archive  = true,
    compress = true,
    acls = true,
    verbose = true,
    owner = true,
    group = true,
    perms = true,
    temp_dir="/tmp/",


    -- binary = "/usr/local/bin/rsync",
    -- sparse = true,
    -- update = true,
    -- protect_args = false,
    -- whole_file = false,
    -- links = true,
    _extra = { "--omit-dir-times" },
    rsh = "ssh -p 44400 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
    -- rsync_path = "/usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/rsync"
  },
  delete = true
}
```

I can copy css folder but cannot copy newsimages folder. Lsyncd service stopping. Please help me.

```
root@main2:/ # sysctl kern.maxfiles kern.maxfilesperproc kern.openfiles
kern.maxfiles: 500000
kern.maxfilesperproc: 490000
kern.openfiles: 274
```